# PHP's imagepng() method saves an invalid image

Tags: php, gd

I am using the GD library to automatically generate a thumbnail version of an uploaded image.  I call the appropriate `image____()` function to save in the same format as the original.  My code works fine for JPEG and GIF, but if I upload a PNG file, the resulting thumbnail is invalid.  It actually only contains 33 bytes (with any source PNG that I've tried so far).  This image does not display in the browser, nor can it be opened by Preview (on MacOS).

I use **imagecreatetruecolor**() along with **imagecopyresampled**() to generate the thumbnail, like this:

```
function _resizeImageToFit($resource, $size)
{
    $sourceWidth = imagesx($resource);
    $sourceHeight = imagesy($resource);  
    if($sourceWidth >= $sourceHeight) {
        // landscape or square
        $newHeight = 1.0*$size/$sourceWidth*$sourceHeight;
        $newWidth = $size;
    }
    else {
        // portrait
        $newWidth = 1.0*$size/$sourceHeight*$sourceWidth;
        $newHeight = $size;
    }
    $thmb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($thmb, $resource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
    return $thmb;
}
```

Below is the version info of my setup (It's MAMP Version 1.9.4)

PHP Version 5.3.2
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Here is an example of an invalid generated thumbnail image (PNG):

```
âPNG
```

IHDRdaØMì∞

Comment: What do you do with the return value of this function? Save to file system or serve it directly?

Comment: I call `$saveSuccess = $imagesave($thumbResource, $thumbPath, 100);` followed by `imagedestroy($thumbResource);`.  I use a variable for the image function call here based on the image type.  When this is a PNG, the call ends up being `imagepng()`.  $saveSuccess (the value returned by imagepng) is set to TRUE indicating success, even though the image is corrupt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my error.  imagepng() takes a quality value range of 0 to 9, while imagejpeg() takes a range of 0 to 100 and imagegif() doesn't take any such parameter.  I was trying to save a PNG with a quality of 100.

So, this is a lovely case of RTM.  Thanks for your responses.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
/** 
* Crop new images using the source image
*
* @param  string $source - Image source
* @param  string $destination - Image destination
* @param  integer $thumbW - Width for the new image
* @param  integer $thumbH - Height for the new image
* @param  string $imageType - Type of the image
* 
* @return bool 
*/
function cropImage($source, $destination, $thumbW, $thumbH, $imageType) 
{
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($source);
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;
    if ($width*$thumbH>$height*$thumbW) {
        $x = ceil(($width - $height*$thumbW/$thumbH)/2);
        $width = $height*$thumbW/$thumbH;
    } else {
        $y = ceil(($height - $width*$thumbH/$thumbW)/2);
        $height = $width*$thumbH/$thumbW;
    }

    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbW, $thumbH) or die ('Can not use GD');

    /*
    if ($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } else if ($extension=='gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } else if ($extension=='png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    } 
    */
    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
            break;
    }

    if (!@imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbW, $thumbH, $width, $height)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        imagejpeg($newImage, $destination,100);
        imagedestroy($image);
        return true;
    }
}
```